# JQuery: custom function for multiple selectors, some inside others - selects the outermost one only

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have been reading here and there about multiple JQuery selectors but I couldn't get the answer I was looking for.

```
$.fn.extend({
    sayHi:function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('class') + ' says hi');
    }
}
$('.class1,.class2').sayHi();
```

The last selector always calls the outermost item among the listed ones. Here's what happens:

```
<div class="class1"><!-- only this one gets selected -->
    <div class="class2"></div>
</div>
```

What is the most elegant way to make it select all the indicated selectors no matter whether they're wrapped by any other selector(s) indicated?

**EDIT:**

I know I can use it like

```
$('.class1').sayHi();
$('.class2').sayHi();
```

but I'm willing to bind it into a single call (I'm actually using more than 2 selectors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.sayHi = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr('class') + ' says hi');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.class1, .class2').sayHi();
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was looking for, though I would not think `.each` would make it happen. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is not with the multiple selector but with how `attr` works.

First, inside the plugin method, `this` already refers to a jQuery object, there is not need to pass it to jQuery again.
Secondly, [`attr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will always return the value of the first of the selected elements (emphasis mine):

> Get the value of an attribute for the **first element** in the set of matched elements.

`this` references the two selected elements, the first one will always be `.class1`.

You therefore have to *iterate* over the selected elements and access the attribute of each element individually, just as [@Eli shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9560452/218196). This is a common pattern for jQuery plugins.

The [jQuery Plugins/Authoring page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) might be worth reading as well.

Comment: In my real code I was referring to a data item (which has been assigned previously to all those selectors) but interestingly it kept catching the outermost selector just like it does in my example here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @inhan: `.data` behaves the same way for *retrieving* stored data: *"Returns value at named data store for the **first element** in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value)."*. The documentation normally tells you if a method is only applied to the first or all elements. And in general, whenever a method *returns* a value and you know it is a string, it's most likely some value from the first element. Otherwise, it would have to return an array containing one value from each element.

Comment: Never thought it might apply to data, too. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you might have the following html:

```
<div class="class1" id="outer1">
    <div class="class2 inner">
        <div class="class1 inner">
            <div class="class2 inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class2" id="outer2">
    <div class="class1 inner">
        <div class="class2 inner">
            <div class="class1 inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you want a selector like:

```
$(".class1, .class2");
```

But filtered so that only `outer1` and `outer2` get selected, not those of class `inner`, is that right?

The following will select all elements of either class and then exclude any elements descendent from either class, thus only leaving the highest ancestor of either class, ie the outer-most element:

```
$(".class1, .class2").not(".class1 *, .class2 *")
```

Comment: Well this structure is a bit different than mine. I'm not actually trying to eliminate anything. Adapted to your example, I was trying to select all `$('.class1')` and `$('.class2')` items. I was expecting it to select all the divs there. @Eli's solution using **each** seems to have solved it.

Comment: I'm not clear what the goal is then.  Aren't you trying to eliminate the elements inside of elements where both match?

Comment: Oh, I misread the code example. I thought you only wanted that first one selected. You meant only that one *was* being selected, which isn't what you wanted.

Comment: If that is the case, wouldn't $("[class]") select them all, going off of your example?

Comment: Nevermind again.  I'm going to reread the question and be quiet for a bit.

Comment: @felix's comment explains it. It just stops looking for the inner items once it catches an element. I was trying to avoid it because I had many inner elements along with the wrapping one.